# How to add multiple Checkbox value to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox

I have a database named "student1905" where there is a table named "programmata" where there is a column named "Periorismoi".

I have a page where there are some checkboxes. All i want to do is add the value of the TICKED  (selected) checkboxes into the column "Periorismoi" with a "," between them. I am thinking of a function where variable named "ids" will take all the values. And then ids will be added in the column. But something is wrong and I cannot find it although I am googling like hell. Here is a part of the code from the page with the checkboxes :

```
    <form action="Insert4.php" method="POST" periorismoi="periorismoi">
        <p>
<input type="checkbox" name="periorismoi[]" value="TRALALALA">Προβλήματα Όρασης<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="periorismoi[]" value="2">Προβλήματα Ακοής<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="periorismoi[]" value="3">Κινητικά Προβλήματα <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="periorismoi[]" value="4">Σοβαρές κινητικές διαταραχές (σε αναπηρικό καροτσάκι)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="periorismoi[]" value="5">Κατάθλιψη<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="periorismoi[]" value="6">Άγχος<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="periorismoi[]" value="7">Δεν μπορεί να γράφει και να διαβάζει
</p>
<p align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="ΠΡΟΣΘΗΚΗ"></p>
<p align="left"> <br></p>
</form>
</body>
```

and here is the code from the Insert (to database) page I had at the beginning which is wrong because it is putting at the database the checkbox number:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'student1905','123456');
mysql_select_db('student1905');
if(!$link) 
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
    $periorismoi = $_POST['periorismoi'];
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($periorismoi);$i++){ 
    $sql="INSERT INTO programmata (Auxon,Title,Periorismoi)
    VALUES ('','$title','$periorismoi[$i]')";
    mysql_query($sql);
  }
      header("Location:dokimastiko.php"); ; 
    }
?>
```

I tried to do that but it didnt work:

```
$i = 0;
$ids = "";
$first = true;
while(isset($_POST['periorismos[$i]'])) 
{
        if($first) {
                $first = false;
        } else {
                $ids += ","
        }
        $ids += $_POST['periorismos[$i]'];
        $i++;
}
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'student1905','123456');
mysql_select_db('student1905');
if(!$link) 
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
       mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
       $sql = "INSERT INTO programmata (Auxon, Title, Periorismoi) VALUE ('','$title','$ids')";
       mysql_query($sql);
      header("Location:dokimastiko.php"); ; 
    }
```

Comment: you should just use `implode(',', $_POST['periorismoi'])`

Comment: Programming Student's and yours helped me. THANX !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the line:

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($periorismoi);$i++){
```

Use:

```
$len = sizeof($periorismoi);
for($i=0; $i<$len;$i++){
```

As the function `sizeof` is getting called for seven times currently.

In the later case, we are calling it only once.

Comment: It now takes the value ! Although I will need to put the UTF-8 first. Now how can i take multiple values into the column ? For example i check no1 and no2. I want them to be seen in the column like this:
value1 , value2

Answer (score 0):

Probably the quickest and easiest way to do this is just to encode the periorismoi[] array into a JSON string and store that in the table column.

Something like this

```
<?php
if ($POST){
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'student1905','123456');
    mysql_select_db('student1905');
    if(!$link){
        die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        $periorismoi = $_POST['periorismoi'];
        $sql="INSERT INTO programmata SET Auxon = '' Title = ".$title." Periorismoi = ".json_encode($periorismoi).";";
        if(mysql_query($sql)){
            echo "worked";
        } else echo "didnt work";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I did that but when i check the database, no column added :(

Comment: this wouldn't "Add a column" it would simply insert a record into your table with the values from the form when it's posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$per = $_POST['periorismoi'];    
foreach($per as $p) {
  $periorismoi=$p.",";
}

$sql="INSERT INTO programmata (Periorismoi) VALUES ($periosismoi)";
mysqli_query($sql);
```

something like that? All you have to do is make a string with the values of the array and but a ',' between them.
Hope this help you!!